# Vue: How to enable multi page in an existing SPA project?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a single page (SPA) application written in Vue.

Now I need a separate page that should be available without being signed in.

To me it seems like a need to enable multi page app (MPA). I see in the documentation (https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages) that I need to set this up in `vue.config.js`. But I the documentation is unclear to me. Do I need to edit/rerun the Vue CLI setup? Or do some webpack changes. Just adding a new page entry with corresponding files does not work (webpack does not insert anything in html-file).

Comment: You can have a spa with some routes allowed if signed in and some not. Aren't you checking permission in router?

Comment: Yes @catmal, it's possible to route to a view and hide common stuff like side menu etc if not signed in. But the MPA approach seem much cleaner and less hackish. I want to explore this option first

Comment: I was meaning a router guard, something like if (!store.state.signedIn && to.path !== '/signin' next('/signin')
else next()

Comment: This approach is not hackish and it's opinable that's less cleaner. And if you use that you don't need to hide stuff in the view with v-if or v-show.

Comment: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards

Answer (score 0):

From SPA View, i would likely go like this

Inside `/views` folder

```
- HomePage.vue (no auth)
- Login.vue 
  - /users/ subfolder (auth needed)
    - DashBoard.vue
    - About.vue
    etc
```

Then define the routes (paths,components,etc.) with `requiresAuth` as auth-check, redirects back to the route with `HomePage.vue`component then.

and SPA mostly comes with MPA Challenges such as SEO, SSR concerns. The routing roughly the same to Vue/Nuxt.